# Why Laravel Builder object that stored in a variable (method scope) can be modified by another method in same class?

Tags: php, laravel, oop, eloquent, builder

Let's say if have a model called ReportType with some fields (id, name, created_at).

In my controller (ReportTypeController.php)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $reportType = ReportType::whereNotNull('created_at');

        $this->addSomeConditions($reportType);

        return $reportType;
    }

    private function addSomeConditions($reportType)
    {
        $reportType->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3]);
    }

}
```

The `$reportType` variable in index will have `whereIn` condition from method `addSomeConditions` even though `$reportType` is not pass by reference and the `addSomeConditions` method have no any return value. Is the class builder is implementing singleton, which there will be only one object alive inside this class?

Comment: because its an Object, the variable technically only holds an identifier to it, so when you pass it around you are just creating another reference to it basically ... it is not like other variables that will be copied .... this is why they are used as "Builders", the builder object is holding all the information about the query you are building internally and you are always referencing that same object, but no, not a singleton

Comment: Try using query scopes. It's pretty much what you're trying to do.

Comment: sure, thank you @IGP for reminding :D